# How can I export a video with audio?

Tags: rendering, audio

I rendered my youtube intro, but, there is no audio. How can I get blender to output a video with audio?

Comment: What audio do you have in blender? Did you edit your intro in the VSE and add in sound? Because the only sound I hear when I render my animations is the CPU fan.

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties panel below in out put change from png to MPEG and u will get more options below then go to audio codec change from none to MP3
and then render hope u get the audio and video